# How to update state when Navigating back to a page Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, setstate

i am creating a social media like app, when user clicks on post ,it redirects to a commentpage,in commentspage data is coming from a seperate API,so when go back using Navigator.pop(context), the data in home is not updated, if pressed like button,its not reflecting in ui, but updating in Api,

i wrapped Navigator with setstate but its not reflecting,

Answer (score 1):

Use this on navigator push `Navigator.push(context).then((value)=>setState((){});` when it pop the screen it will run the setState

Comment: but when i do this the entire page is getting reloaded  from start, i mean its not going back to the post where i clicked

Answer (score 1):

Use this sentence to go to the second page so the function will wait second screen to close

```
bool result = await Navigator.push(context);
if(result){setState((){});}
```

when u close the second screen use this sentence `Navigator.pop(context, true);`

so when u comment has been posted successfully, u will back to screen one and complete the function if result boolean is true,  else do nothing.

Comment: what will i pass for route,if i am not using named routing,Navigator.push(context,route).

Comment: you can pass arguments via route, read this article [Pass arguments to a named route](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments)